# C++ Creating a function, like a variable, change its body later and then call it later

Tags: c++, c++11, variables, lambda, mutable

I'm trying to create a dummy function inside of a class, whichs' body will be changed later in `int main()`. And then I'd like to call this body changed func in the class. Is there a way to achieve this?

Something like this:

```
class Animation {
public:

    //Don't know what to write at the next line
    function<void>/*?*/ whenCompleted = []() mutable { /* Dummy func. */ };
    .
    .
    .
    void startAnimation() { /* Do stuff, then */ animationEnded(); }
    void animationEnded() { whenCompleted(); }

}score;


int main(){
    score.whenCompleted = { /* new body for whenCompleted() */ }
    score.startAnimation();
}
```

Comment: So you are basically asking how to use std::function?

Comment: You can treat `std::function<> whenComplete`, as you would a regular class member, initialise it in the constructor.

Comment: @user253751 if it'll allow me to do the edit in `int main()` , then I guess. I couldn't get these syntaxes to work. Will std::function let me do this?

Comment: You can't edit a function, only change one function to a completely different one. Luckily, that's exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically have the right idea

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
 
class Animation
{
public:
    std::function<void()> whenCompleted;
 
    void startAnimation() { animationEnded(); }
    void animationEnded() { whenCompleted(); }
};
 
int main()
{
    Animation score;
    score.whenCompleted = [](){ std::cout << "all done"; };
    score.startAnimation();
}
```

Will [output](https://ideone.com/wN53oI)

```
all done
```

You could also add a constructor for `Animation` that accepts a function to initialize `whenCompleted` with

```
Animation(std::function<void()>&& onCompleted) : whenCompleted(onCompleted) {}
```

which would modify `main` to

```
int main()
{
    Animation score{[](){ std::cout << "all done"; }};
    score.startAnimation();
}
```